# Create a vector with substrings

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let hello = r##"#[0] !sell 0 100 ars \"belo lemon\" 1"##;
    let x: Vec<&str> = hello.split(" ").collect();
    println!("{x:?}");
}
```

I want to have this output

```
["#[0]", "sell", "0", "100", "ars", "belo lemon", "1"]
```

I am kinda new in rust, I can't find how to do it, any ideas?

Comment: Will there be escaped quotes inside the strings?

Comment: yes, let me update the post

Comment: No no, I mean is something like `"they said, \"hi\""` possible input - where there are escape quotes inside the string.

Comment: I wrote some really bad code to do it which you can find [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=993c800c74ff11f2161e637ef88fbfef) using some state and `fold`. I was gonna use regex but it seems that Rust doesn't support negative lookbehinds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with [`Regex`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.6.0/regex/).

The idea of this regex is to consider two branches:

- quote, anything but quote, quote
- anything (not empty) but quote or space

When dealing with the capture, we have to test which of these two branches matches.

Revised in order to avoid owned strings and to remove the surrounding quotes in the result.
(Note that the example in the question has changed since the first post; this answer does not match anymore the situation in the question)

```rust
// [dependencies]
// regex = "1.5"
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new(r#"["]([^"]*)["]|([^" ]+)"#).unwrap();
    let hello = r#"[0] sell 0 100 ars "belo lemon" 1"#;
    let x: Vec<&str> = re
        .captures_iter(hello)
        .map(|cap| {
            if let Some(quoted) = cap.get(1) {
                quoted
            } else {
                cap.get(2).unwrap()
            }
            .as_str()
        })
        .collect();
    println!("{x:?}");
}
/*
["[0]", "sell", "0", "100", "ars", "belo lemon", "1"]
*/
```